# code won't display the error message in the else statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, authentication

I have a bit problem with my basic login sample. The error message in the else statement won't display when the username and password combination is incorrect. Is it because of `while` loop? I need help, please.

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=project', 'root', '');

if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");

    if(empty($username) || empty($password)) {
        echo 'Empty';
    }

    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        if($username == $row->username && $password == $row->password) {
            echo 'Logged in';
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect username and password combination';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you found the answer to this question, I'd advice you to read up on [SQL-Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: _"Won't display"_ As in nothing shows up on your screen or is it displaying the "Logged in" echo instead?

Comment: @Epodax if it is correct combination, it displays "Logged in". If not, it displays nothing (null)

Comment: If $username or $passwords doesn't match any column, query literally return 0. If you use this 0 in while condition it evaluate it as false and no loop happen. Use if statement instead.

Answer (score 2):

No need to recheck query result. Because, if query success, then **fetch()** function will return result row, otherwise return false.

**Change below code**

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    if($username == $row->username && $password == $row->password) {
        echo 'Logged in';
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect username and password combination';
    }
}
```

**TO**

```
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if($row){
  echo 'Logged in';
}else{
  echo 'Incorrect username and password combination';
}
```

*Note:* **username** field should be unique column, Because of your login purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it won't display. It is because when you fetch your results, it returns no rows, or simply empty. That said, code inside the `while` loop won't execute.

You might as well perform a query that **counts** the number of rows returned based on the username and password conditions.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");

if (($row = $result->fetchColumn()) != 0) {
    // logged in
}
else {
    // incorrect username and password
}
```

Comment: so `fetchColumn()` is better way

Comment: Yes, if you only want to select the number of rows/row count that match your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement only returns values if both username and password are correct. So if it isn't correct, the code in your loop won't execute.

Try removing the password-check from your sql-statement:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username';"
```